# Error (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer for rest API post method request using PHP

Tags: php, rest, curl, token

The Response should be XML, but I'm getting error like:

> (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer

while sending the request to REST API using headers. Here is the sample request according to the client:

```
POST http://api.toyotautrust.in/1.0/olx/inventory HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Authorization: Token ******-****-****-****-***********
Host: api.toyotautrust.in
Content-Length: 52
```

Here is my Request code written in PHP using cURL

```
$headers1=[
'POST /1.0/olx/inventory HTTP/1.1',
        'Host: api.toyotautrust.in',
        'User-Agent: Fiddler',
        'Authorization: Token' .$atoken1,
        'Content-Length: 52'];
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.toyotautrust.in/1.0/olx/inventory');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers1);
$response1 = curl_exec($ch1);
print_r($response1);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $status_code1;
```

Comment: Remove "POST...", "Host", "Content-Length" from the custom headers and let curl make them itself. Then you probably want to submit some actual data as well (52 bytes I presume).

Comment: @DanielStenberg:  Can you please give an example

Comment: @DanielStenberg: Now i'm getting Error #:Recv failure: Connection was reset

Comment: If you changed the code/error, then I suggest you update the question or it will be impossible to understand where we are now. "Connection was reset" happens on a connection level that curl mostly cannot affect so there's something fundamentally broken. Perhaps you should use HTTPS for example?

Answer (score 0):

I have failed to send these two header in POST request

```
'User-Agent:Fiddler',
"Content-length: 0",
```

After adding these two headers, it's working fine. Before sending your request to server, Please ask server side people about headers and parameters